# Xamarin Android - Access textview onclick within a Fragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to access a TextView that is part of a Fragment, in a seperate Click function.

```
public class FragmentHome : AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_home, container, false);

            // Initialise View's Textviews & TextInput
            TextView genderButton= view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.genderButton);
            TextView secondButton = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.secondButton);
            TextInputEditText firstInput = view.FindViewById<TextInputEditText>(Resource.Id.firstInput);

            // set up click actions
            genderButton.Click += GenderButton_Click;

            return view;
        }


        private void GenderButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (genderButton.Text == "Male")
            {
                genderButton.Text = "Female";
            }
            else
            {
                genderButton.Text = "Male";
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to access the Text of the `genderButton`, but I get the error "The name 'genderButton' does not exist in the current context". I have tried adding both

`TextView genderButton = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.genderButton);`

and

`View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_home, container, false); TextView genderButton = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.genderButton);`

But the first one has the problem that `FindViewById` doesn't exist in the current context, and the second option obviously won't work because it would be inflating a new fragment, instead of defining the context for genderButton.

Is there a way where that I can properly define the context for genderButton or send the genderButton data with the Click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a basic C# scope problem.  You are declaring `genderButton` inside of  `OnCreateView`, so it only has scope **inside** that method.  If you want to use it elsewhere in the code, you need to declare it at the **class** level, not inside of a method

```
TextView genderButton;

public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_home, container, false);

            // Initialise View's Textviews & TextInput
            genderButton= view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.genderButton);
            TextView secondButton = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.secondButton);
            TextInputEditText firstInput = view.FindViewById<TextInputEditText>(Resource.Id.firstInput);

            // set up click actions
            genderButton.Click += GenderButton_Click;

            return view;
        }
```